# Central Limit (distribution of scaled random walk)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, central-limit-theorem, moment-generating-functions

I have been reading Steven E Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance Volume II Continuous-time models. I'm trying to understand a theorem from Chapter 3 that says that distribution of scaled random walk $W^{n}(t)$ converges to normal distribution, basically a version of central limit. I can't seem to figure out how he did the following calculation:

[image: Image from the textbook].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_j=1$ with probability $1/2$ and $X_j=-1$ with probability $1/2$. So
$E[e^{\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}X_j}] = \frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}1}+ \frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}(-1)}.$

Comment: So is $X_{j}$ a discrete random variable and are we using the formula for expected value of a discrete random variable i.e. $E(X) = \sum_{k} x_{k}p_{k}$?

Comment: Yes, that's all it is.